# retrieve shape from the selection visio

Tags: vba, visio

I am using Visio 2013 and VBA. I want to retrieve the `Characters` from the Shape I cliked in the page. I tried:

```
Dim s As Visio.shape
Dim c As Visio.Characters
Set s = ActiveWindow.Selection.ContainingShape
c = s.Characters
```

But I have an error when constructing c. Is it possible what I want to do?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1):

The ContainingShape method in a normal drawing page will likely return the page itself (ID = 0) and this does not support a Characters object.  The Selection may contain multiple shapes but the [PrimaryItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff769178.aspx) property will return a single shape or null / nothing if the Selection is empty.

So your code should look something like this:

```
Dim s As Visio.Shape
Dim c As Visio.Characters
Set s = ActiveWindow.Selection.PrimaryItem
If Not s Is Nothing Then
    Set c = s.Characters
    'Do something with characters
End If
```